# embedded text/html object overflow not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sizing embedded `<object>`s while trying to get the wrapping div expand with the size of the embedded -in this case- html page really is a pain.

The last hours I tested many solutions and even the javascript resize onload ones don't seem to work in this case. Iframes didn't help either.

```
<style>
.outer { 
    width:100%;
    position:relative; 
    overflow: visible;
}

.inner {
    min-height: 1600px;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
</style>


<section id="loadersection" class="outer">
    <object id="loader" class="inner" type="text/html" data="/static/index.html">
    </object>
</section>
```

The embedded html page is rather a javascript app and therefore `scrollHeight` at `$(document).ready()`, `onload`, `$(window).load()` returns a height of 150px. The real height when completely loaded is about 1400 px. Are there any events which report a loaded child object?

Is there a way to embed a html page in its full size without scrollbars into a div which expands if e.g. an accordion-menu is expanded within the child object?

Comment: Have a minimal demo for us to see?

Comment: you have two `overflow` rules for your .outer class, which one did you want? And if you want it visible, *how* do you want it visible? `overflow:visible` means "ignore the element boundary", as opposed to `overflow:auto` which means "give me scrollbars if needed" (generally the far superior choice of those two)

Comment: Thanks. Everything should be visible and the divs wrapped around the object are supposed to expand as much as necessary.